# Combine 2 similar grouping MySql queries (same table) in one and loop to get an array in the efficient way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, group-by

```
//last month            
$sqlQuery = "SELECT status, COUNT( id ) AS how_many, status_color
                        FROM table
                        JOIN statuses
                        USING ( status ) 
                        WHERE office_id = ".$office_id."
                        AND wdate
                        BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '-' ,MONTH(CURDATE())-1, '-01'),  '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00' ) 
                        AND DATE_FORMAT( LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59' ) 
                        GROUP BY status, status_color";

//this month                    
$sqlQuery = "SELECT status, COUNT( id ) AS how_many, status_color
                        FROM table
                        JOIN statuses
                        USING ( status )
                        WHERE office_id = ".$office_id."
                        AND wdate
                        BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-' ,MONTH(CURDATE()), '-01'),  '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00' ) 
                        AND NOW() 
                        GROUP BY status, status_color";
```

The loop for one query is simple

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die('Error, query failed: '.mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 1; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $this_month[$i] = array("label" => $row['status'], "fillColor" => $row['status_color'], "data" => array($row['how_many']));
    $i++;
}
```

How can I combine the queries above and have the result one array looking as this

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die('Error, query failed: '.mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 1; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $both_months[$i] = array("label" => $row['status'], "fillColor" => $row['status_color'], "data" => array($row['how_many1']), $row['how_many2']));
    $i++;
}
```

**Note that any query can return zero, one or maximum 4 groups based on waybill_status column**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT status, 
       SUM( wdate 
          BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '-' ,MONTH(CURDATE())-1, '-01'),  '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00' ) 
            AND DATE_FORMAT( LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59' ) ) how_many_1,
       SUM( wdate
          BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-' ,MONTH(CURDATE()), '-01'),  '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00' ) 
            AND NOW() ) how_many_2,
       status_color
FROM table
JOIN statuses
USING ( status ) 
WHERE office_id = ".$office_id."
GROUP BY status, status_color
```

Comment: So easy! How can I not figure this out? Too many things in the same time I think. Many thanks. You saved my day.